# A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'InheritedWidget'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am having problems with my first flutter project, i want to insert a linear gauge on the screen with syncfusion but it gives me this error

A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'InheritedWidget'.

how can i fix it?

this is what i have so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'MyApp'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                    child:SfLinearGauge()
            )
          )      
        );
    }
```

and in pubspec.yaml i have added in dependencies
`syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^19.1.65`

Comment: From `_MyHomePageState.build`, return only the `Scaffold` and remove `MaterialApp` from here. Currently you want to assign a `MaterialApp` as the `home` of another `MaterialApp`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Koltai commented, you don't need another `MaterialApp`

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'MyApp'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SfLinearGauge(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

i tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: There was brackets issue, can you try with pasting my code.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work, what should i do ?

Comment: I am not any issue, can you include your flutter version and which IDE/editor you are using? You can try with `flutter  upgrade` if needed , `flutter clean`  and rebuilding the app

Comment: i am using the latest version of flutter (i launched flutter upgrade) and tried flutter clean on my progect, still nothing
i am using vscode as my main editor

Comment: how about creating a new project and pasting this widget?

Comment: nope, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the NDK version.

```
android/app/build.gradle
```

Before:

```
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

After:

```
ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"
```

Got that hint from
[ould not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421999/ould-not-get-unknown-property-ndkversion-for-extension-flutter-of-type-flutt)

If that does not help, maybe changing SDK version in pubspec.yaml helps

```
environment:
   sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"
```

Dont forget to `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` afterwards