# "Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am really new to Flutter and Dart and while trying to compile my project i got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

what can i do to solve this?

I am using Visual Studo Code and just did a fresh install of Flutter from Git, already tried

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter upgrade
```

but nothing seems to work

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 15):

Go to android>app>build.gradle and change flutter.ndkVersion to the latest stable version.
You can check the latest ndk stable version here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads

You go from this : [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dffVh.png)

to this : [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAifm.png)

Answer (score 4):

Go to file  => android\app\build.gradle

and edit ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
to ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"

You can find out the latest version from the official website
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads

Answer (score 3):

The Solutions above worked for me. Just to re-echo it here.

Go to the `android\app\build.gradle` file

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion // line to change
```

and change `ndkVersion` to the latest version. It is probably around line 30.

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"
```

Comment: this works for me .. downgrading from 3.3.0 to flutter 2.8.0 only changed the environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0' to environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'  and changed the ndk ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion from to ndkVersion "23.1.7779620" .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This usually results from running an 'old' project with the latest flutter version.

You need to upgrade your `com.android.tools.build:gradle` in `project/build.gradle` and `distributionUrl` in `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` to point to a more recent Gradle version.

To update the plugin version, you can check this page [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) to determine the recent version.

For Gradle version, you can use the Gradle releases page.

Here is a snap of the current status of the releases.

> Update Gradle
>
> When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt to also
> update Gradle to the latest available version. You can choose to
> accept the update or manually specify a version based on your
> project's build requirements.
>
> The following table lists which version of Gradle is required for each
> version of the Android Gradle plugin. For the best performance, you
> should use the latest possible version of both Gradle and the plugin.
>
> | Plugin version | Minimum required Gradle version |
> | --- | --- |
> | 8.0 | 8.0 |
> | 7.4 | 7.5 |
> | 7.3 | 7.4 |
> | 7.2 | 7.3.3 |
> | 7.1 | 7.2 |
> | 7.0 | 7.0 |
> | 4.2.0+ | 6.7.1 |

This should solve your error, unless you are using NDK in your android project.