# Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Issue after flutter upgrade Updated ndk but not working working fine for flutter web but on andorid showing
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\flutter practice\Instagramclone\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app, you can also try upgrading the flutter

Comment: I encountered the same problem, did you already find a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ould not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421999/ould-not-get-unknown-property-ndkversion-for-extension-flutter-of-type-flutt)

Answer (score 1):

For now, writing like this works fine.

`android/app/build.gradle  ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"`

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads