# Build gradle failed with exeption,

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

i am getting this error ,
my build.gradlefile

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build file '/home/Ecommerce_app /ecomm/android/build.gradle' line: 27

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'
> > Could not get unknown property 'ndkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: please follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421999/ould-not-get-unknown-property-ndkversion-for-extension-flutter-of-type-flutt

Comment: thanks ndk version error has been solved ,but  still having these                                
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_cas6zxghbef6u00bm21kst9l.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cas6zxghbef6u00bm21kst9l$_run_closure2) values: [build_cas6zxghbef6u00bm21kst9l$_run_closure2@54be917f]

Comment: this link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi

Answer (score 0):

**Change the classpath in gradle.xml**

```
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
```

And also I change the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties(Global Version)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Comment: it was issue with stripe package with flutter 3,after their new package release everything sorted out